# SQL Like using Column Name

Tags: sql, db2, sql-like

I have two tables

```
Table A  
Akey  
Adata Char(20)

Table B  
Bkey  
Bdata varchar(1000)
```

There is a possibility that Adata from Table A lies within Bdata field in Table B. I am using the following SQL, but still, I am unable to get results. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT A.Adata, B.Bdata
FROM Table_A A, Table_B B
WHERE A.Adata LIKE '%' + B.Bdata + '%';
```

I am using `DB2` so I am not sure if its a syntax issue.

I am getting the error:

> Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT"

Comment: (Standard) SQL uses `||` to concatenate strings, not `+`

Answer (score 0):

I correct my previous answer:

```
SELECT A.Adata, B.Bdata FROM Table_A A, Table_B B WHERE LOCATE(A.AData, B.BData)>0
```

This will give you result from Table_A which exist on Table_B. Hope this help

Comment: `A.Adata like B.BData` is equivalent to `A.Adata = B.BData` because there are no wildcards. This is not what Rikin wants as far as I can tell. And btw: the original query **is** using a join - an outdated implicit one in the where clause.

Comment: Ok. CharIndex is SQL Server specific. If you use other DB you have to find a replacement for your especific DB. In Sql Server CharIndex(a, b) return the numeric posicion where string a occurs on string b. In DB2 the equivalent is LOCATE(a, b). Hope this help

Comment: The above query takes forever to run, the number of records are around 50000. I waited for more than an hour for this query to run. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes i understand. The problema is that when you search for a Word in meeddle of a string field is sql you cant use indexes. Like statement will have the same problem. Other option es Split the field on table_b into Word (Searching from the space) copy to a new table and index to search after that. Or you could Split Table_B in parts.... There's no easy solution for your performance isssue